# How do you use lambda and map instead of list comprehension do iterate over multiple lists?

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate the same list using lambda and map which is e as in d.
However, it does not result in a readable list and instead just the positions of maps.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[1,2,3]
d=[v+w for v in a for w in b]
e=list(map(lambda v: (lambda w:v+w, b),a))
```

Comment: can you add an example how you would like to see your output?

Comment: @Vishwas *I'm trying to generate the same list using lambda and map which is e as in d* -- presumably `e` should be the same as `d` if I'm reading that right.

Comment: Yes, I would like to generate the list produced by d which is [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8]

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda needs to have two inputs in order to add two values (or else the first value needs to be already-accessible). I would submit that, instead of nesting lambdas inside each other, just use something like `itertools.product()` to get every (`a`, `b`) pair, and then submit each tuple to the lambda.

```
e = list(map(lambda t:t[0]+t[1], list(itertools.product(a,b))))
```

in which case, why even bother with a lambda?

```
e = list(map(sum, list(itertools.product(a,b))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using lambdas for this (or in general) but you can do this with only built in functions.

```py
e = sum(list(map(lambda v: list(map(lambda w: v + w, b)), a)), [])

# Explanation
# Inner map lambda to add each value from b to v
map(lambda w: v + w, b))

# Outer map lambda that loops through each item in a and runs the inner lambda
map(lambda v: list(map(lambda w: v + w, b)), a)

# Flatten result array
sum(result, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cannot just do this with `map` in any straightforward way, because the equivalent operation here would be a *flat-map* operation, so you'd have to include a `reduce` and materialize the iterator in the internal `map`. It won't be efficient, i.e. it will be quadratic time, but something like

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, map(lambda v: list(map(lambda w: v+w, b)), a))
```

Would work. If you want to "cheat", use itertools, but this *will* be efficient:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda v: map(lambda w: v+w, b), a)))
```